# comas with quote mark right behind

Tags: python, regex

I need to format a string dictionary before convert it into dict
I tried it with regex:

```
        decmark_reg = re.compile('(?<=\d),(?=\d)')
        dict_decmark = decmark_reg.sub('.',dict_quotes)
        convertedDict = json.loads(dict_decmark)
```

but then I realized it mess with "fingerOne_OffTimes" values

```
    dict_str = '{"level":0,6,     
                 "params":{
                 "startLvlTime":1114.3851318359375,
                 "fingerOne_OffTimes":[459,4716491699219,78532]}}
```

desired result

```
    dict_str = '{"level":0.6,                                      # 0,6 -> 0.6
                 "params":{
                 "startLvlTime":1114.3851318359375,
                 "fingerOne_OffTimes":[459,4716491699219,78532]}}  # no change
```

Would need a pattern that detect all comas but ones which have quot mark right behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/012Q78/1)):

```py
import re

dict_str = """\
{"level":0,6,     
 "params": {
 "startLvlTime":1114.3851318359375,
 "fingerOne_OffTimes":[459,4716491699219,78532]}}"""

pat = re.compile(r"(\[.*?\])|(\d,\d)")

dict_str = pat.sub(
    lambda g: g.group(1) or g.group(2).replace(",", "."), dict_str
)
print(dict_str)
```

Prints:

```
{"level":0.6,     
 "params": {
    "startLvlTime":1114.3851318359375,
    "fingerOne_OffTimes":[459,4716491699219,78532]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match strings that consist of digits and at least two commas, and then match your pattern in all other contexts:

```py
decmark_reg = re.compile(r'(\d+(?:,\d+){2,})|(?<=\d),(?=\d)')
dict_decmark = decmark_reg.sub(lambda x: x.group(1) or '.', dict_quotes)
```

*Details*:

- `(\d+(?:,\d+){2,})` - Group 1: one or more digits and then two or more sequences of a comma and one or more digits
- `|` - or
- `(?<=\d),(?=\d)` - a comma that is enclosed with digits on both ends

If Group 1 matches, its value is returned, else, the `.` is returned.